# Can I use a Kentico macro to get a partial path?

Tags: kentico

I would like to know if it is possible to use kentico macros (not necessarily coding a custom one) to access part of the rewritten URL's Path.

Example: http://www.mysite.com/Category/Subcategory/

I would like to get the last part (Subcategory) so that I may then filter content dynamically. The reason I want to use the macro is to simply not have to have 20+ different page templates only so I can have different web part properties.

Comment: Yes, there are macros that will resolve to paths like "~/{0}/{1}/%", etc. but it has limits. What exactly are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Basically I want to pass the 'Subcategory' (ideally also replacing all dashes by spaces') and pass it to the Category field of an Article List webpart so that I can get all of the relevant content -- I should add that the content I want to list is from another section of the site completely. I want to filter using the "Subcategory" however.

Comment: Are the levels at different depths? For example, sometimes /1/2 and sometimes 1/2/3? If so, the macro solution probably isn't the solution. Why don't you use the default document path and then a Transform and Selected Item Transform?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about doing so to be honest. I thought a macro would be the solution to my problem to be honest -- The content I want to retrieve is always at the same level. The reason I want to do a macro is I have 20 different 'Subcategory' level pages. I don't want them all to have an ad-hoc template just so I can specify which content to display for each page explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Portal templates, and you don't want an 'all items in all subcategories' list on the parent:

1. Create an Article List web part on the parent page — parent to all the sub-categories.
2. Set the web part `Path` to `/{0}/{1}/{2}/%` (if your path was /Home/Parent/Subcategory for example) or something similar for your environment.
3. Use the default setting of `Inherit` for the page template for all subcategory pages.

This will not show anything on the parent page, and the sub-categories will show only the documents under themselves. Note: If you want the subcategory items to have their own views when user digs down to `/{0}/{1}/{2}/item`, you may need to filter by changing template inheritance, or Document Types on the web part, or something like that if you don't want the whole sub-category list to also show on the item-specific pages.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you are suggesting. This would work for a problem I solved last week pertaining to another situation. I would need to filter contents by actual Kentico Categories however (the ones that are like tags basically). I may not have expressed that clearly enough in my first post, i'm sorry.

Comment: @Codehelpneeded: So you're saying `Category/Subcategory` aren't Page document types, they are formal Kentico Categories that you are using that you're URL mapping to show all documents on the site that are set to use those formal Kentico Categories?

Comment: Category/subcategory are page document types.
What I want to do is retrieve the subcategory from the URL and use it as a search string (it matches the name of a Kentico Cateogry)

Comment: @Codehelpneeded: Search into what? A Web part Property Path, Search result, Custom table, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom macro or, you can also use the string operations which are allowed within macros. Please see http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/6_0/devguide/available_macro_methods.htm#string_methods (and you can e.g. use the EndsWith or TrimStrart or something similar).

However, I think the best way would be to create a custom macro which will exactly fit. There might be some combination of macros and macro functions - but I think it is faster just to code a custom one which will cover your need 100%.

Also, you can take a look on the K# if there is something that will fit - http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/6_0/devguide/ksharp_syntax.htm